# laravel Maatwebsite validate sum multi column

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

hi im using Maatwebsite with laravel everything working so good so far .. 
but i want to update excel like this ..

```
number      date            amount
1           2020-01-01      10
1           2020-01-01      -5
1           2020-01-01      -5
2           2020-02-02      20
2           2020-02-02      -20
3           2020-03-03      50  
3           2020-03-03      -50
3           2020-03-03      40
3           2020-03-03      -40
```

what i want thats the sum of the amount with number 1 sould return 0 or end the import

```
number      date            amount
1           2020-01-01      10
1           2020-01-01      -5
1           2020-01-01      -5
```

how can i check this (10 + -5 + -5 == 0) or fail
and for 2 and 3 ect ..

thanks a lot

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Could you add more examples, as well as your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explained all the steps in comments but I will explain here as well.

When you loop through each row, you first need to grab all the rows where `number` field is `1`, `2` or `3`, what ever the number is currently in the iteration.

In this case, the first loop results will be:

```
number      date            amount
1           2020-01-01      10
1           2020-01-01      -5
1           2020-01-01      -5
```

Then you sum (add up) the values from the `amount` column.

In this case, it will sum like this:

```
10
-5
-5
-----
0
```

If the answer is **not** `0`, take the current sheet (`$sheet`) and return what you currently have, to be exported.

---

**Full class:**

```php
...
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;

class ExampleExport implements FromArray
{
    public function array() : array
    {
        // EXAMPLE hardcoded data for the purpose of this demo
        $rows = [
            [
                'number' => 1,
                'date' => '2020-01-01',
                'amount' => 10
            ],
            [
                'number' => 1,
                'date' => '2020-01-01',
                'amount' => -5
            ],
            [
                'number' => 1,
                'date' => '2020-01-01',
                'amount' => -5
            ],
            [
                'number' => 2,
                'date' => '2020-02-02',
                'amount' => 20
            ],
            [
                'number' => 2,
                'date' => '2020-02-02',
                'amount' => -20 // <-------- Change this to -21 to test
            ],
            [
                'number' => 3,
                'date' => '2020-03-03',
                'amount' => 50
            ],
            [
                'number' => 3,
                'date' => '2020-03-03',
                'amount' => -50
            ],
            [
                'number' => 3,
                'date' => '2020-03-03',
                'amount' => 40
            ],
            [
                'number' => 3,
                'date' => '2020-03-03',
                'amount' => -40
            ],
        ];

        // EXAMPLE hardcoded data for the purpose of this demo
        $rows = collect($rows);

        // You probably going to get this from your database so should look like this:
        // $rows = \App\Model::all(['number', 'date', 'amount']); // OR below
        // $rows = DB::table('examples')->select(['number', 'date', 'amount'])->get();

        // Blank sheet
        $sheet = [];

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            // Get all the rows where the `number` field has the same value,
            // for example 1, 2, or 3, then sum the `amount` field (add up).
            //
            // If the amount does not add up to 0, stop and return what you currently got
            if ($rows->where('number', $row['number'])->sum('amount') !== 0) {
                return $sheet;
            }

            // Else, add them to the sheet and continue.
            $sheet[] = $row;
        }

        return $sheet;
    }
}
```

---

**Results:**

When `amount` adds up to `0`:

[image: Successful results]

When `amount` does not add up to `0`:

[image: Unsuccessful results]